# Increase precision in numbers

Tags: macos, numbers

In Numbers, when I enter `0.981`, it gets automatically formatted as `1`. How can I increase the precision?

When I double click on the cell I can see `0.981` but as soon as I deselect it, it goes back to `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Cell tab of the sidebar you can select the number of decimal places or set it to "Auto". Pick whatever best suits your needs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How can I change the precision in a corresponding plot?

Comment: Welcome! I don't know without checking it, but I guess you can find the answer with a quick search! In any case, this is probably a different question.